# Through a FORM I want to return a value to a Column

Tags: forms, input-field

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

```
Dim Which_Day As Integer
Dim Damage_Average As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer

Which_Day = CByte(TextBox1.Value)

For Counter = 1 To 29 'Loops for 29 members
Damage_Average = Range("g" & Counter + 1).Value 'Reads value of celles, column G
Range("i" & Counter + 1).Value = Damage_Average

Next
```

End Sub

Now ... I have the above added to the execute button on a FORM.
The FORM has one input field which simply asks "Which day do you want to export data to?"

If "1" is returned as value in input field I want the value to be returned to column "i", as above.
If "2" is returned as value in input field I want the value returned to column "j".
If "3" is returned as value in input field I want the value returned to column "k", etc. etc..

I can't make it work - Any suggestions ?